Ona'as Mamon by Non-Jew
Ona'as Mamon for non-Jews
The case of a nursing home that is Jewish owned with a vending machine that charges $2.25 a bottle, when they can be charging less, i.e. one can get a whole case of water for $5.
Is that ona'ah? What if a Jew buys from the machine?

goyim live in the nursing home

Is it not the usual practice in vending machines to sell things at a price that reflects the convenience of having it right there, right now?

Talmudic Ona'ah is a matter of communal agreement. In our modern societies, those are governmental regulations. Under the "Dina Demalchusa Dina" principle, all prices that comply with governmental regulations are considered Ona'ah-free.

IIRC, there's no Ona'as Mamon specifically for Gentiles as whatever is considered fair and acceptable for them falls under Dina Demalchusa Dina.
